# Windows free email client which can change custom fonts

Tags: windows, email, email-client

I am looking for a Windows email client which has options to change font in reading pane.

Comment: I doubt that is the *only* requirement that you have for your email client - other features seem much more important. So please [edit] your question and describe what else is required. [Reading this helps](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/), which is available for Windows, OS X and Linux, is free software and you can set the default font settings in the settings like here:

[image]
You can also disallow messages to use other fonts, so your setting wins always:
[image]